# Change borderStroke to random color every few seconds

Tags: swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI and trying to set the strokeBorder of my circle to randomly change color every 2 seconds from an array. I've tried randomElement() since that's what I used to set random background color in the past examples. Just getting stuck and would appreciate guidance on how to approach it.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

let redBorder = Color(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, opacity: 1)
let orangeBorder = Color(red: 255/255, green: 127/255, blue: 0/255, opacity: 1)
let yellowBorder = Color(red: 255/255, green: 222/255, blue: 0/255, opacity: 1)

let randomBorderColors = [redBorder, orangeBorder, yellowBorder]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var borderColor = redBorder

    let numTimer = Timer.publish(every: 2.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader{g in
            ZStack {
                //set strokeBorder to random color from array
                Circle().strokeBorder(Color.red, lineWidth: 30)
                Text("Hello World")
                .font(.system(size: g.size.height > g.size.width ? g.size.width * 0.4: g.size.height * 0.4))
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the code for `onReceive`, Following should work perfectly.
You might have to work on the random color logic coz the current one might give same number multiple times as you only have three colors.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

let redBorder = Color(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, opacity: 1)
let orangeBorder = Color(red: 255/255, green: 127/255, blue: 0/255, opacity: 1)
let yellowBorder = Color(red: 255/255, green: 222/255, blue: 0/255, opacity: 1)

let randomBorderColors = [redBorder, orangeBorder, yellowBorder]

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var borderColor = redBorder

    let numTimer = Timer.publish(every: 2.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ g in
            ZStack {
                //set strokeBorder to random color from array
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(self.borderColor, lineWidth: 30)
                    .onReceive(self.numTimer, perform: { _ in
                        self.borderColor = randomBorderColors.randomElement() ?? redBorder
                        print(self.borderColor)
                    })
                Text("Hello World")
                .font(.system(size: g.size.height > g.size.width ? g.size.width * 0.4: g.size.height * 0.4))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: onReceive! Thanks Harshal!